# What is "thenable" value?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I looked at the documentation here: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.resolve.html

and I saw the line: " If value is not a **thenable**, a fulfilled Promise is returned with value as its fulfillment value".

My question is what is a thenable value. For example, I saw the following code:

```
Promise.resolve("http://xxxx...")
```

The value in this case is a string of HTTP address. What is a thenable HTTP address?

I'm not asking what is the difference between a promise and a thenable object. My question is how can I know of a string is thenable or not.

Comment: That string, for example, is not a thenable.

Comment: What strings are thenable, if any?

Comment: None actually. A primitive value can never be a thenable object.